# Linking equipment (EQUI) To Document information table (DRAW)

Tags: sap-erp

Fairly straight forward question: How can I link the equipment master data table EQUI to Document information table DRAW?

Comment: How do you link documents with equipment? Via `IE02`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, via table DRAD. Use `objkey` field:

```
DRAD -> objkey <==> equnr <- EQUI
```

You should filter `DRAD` first by `DOKOB` which is SAP object we are referring to (equipment in our case), then probably filter by Document Type `DOKAR` and then find appropriate object number (=equipment number) in appropriate master table specified in `DOKAB` (`EQUI` in our case).

Here is the sample:

[image]

Comment: This is also the one I was looking for! Thanks for answering both of my questions!